# email alert on a multiple related objects

Tags: email, email-template, email-alert, visual-flows

I have a junction object which holds multiple accounts, whenever a contact is created on one of the accounts I send an email to the primary contact of the related account. I'm using flow to achieve this, however when I call the email alert from the flow I'm only able to pass the contact id(single parameter) of the related account and send the email but with in the email template how do I show the information of the contact that was inserted?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches:

1. I think you have created email template based on your junction object. you could create visualforce email template which will show the contact details based on contact Id.
2. You can create few formula fields on Junction object for those contact attributes which you are exposing in the email. Then in the email template you can refer the formula field.

I would suggest to go for approach 2 in case if you have few contact attributes and this is pure configuration.